# How to iterate each line of text file and assign it as variable value in each iteration?

Tags: bash

I have a folder which contains hundreds of files. Also, another file which contains the name of all files in the directory as follows:

```
>myfile.txt

11j
33t
dsvd33
343
im@3
```

I would like to write bash script such that, it goes each line of myfile.txt, and select the file name (file id) in each iteration and path it to my CrunchMe.
More specifically:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ID in myfile.txt:
  # do this
  CrunchMe ID
 end
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: `another file which contains the name of all files` ? Do you have a guideline on how your files are named? Apart from that your question itself is incomplete. For instance how would you even represent a filename with a new line in your file of file names?

Comment: `another file which contains the name of all files` - Why would you even rely on that provided you have other (reliable) ways to iterate thru files to perform some action like `find .. | while -rd ''` combination?

Answer (score 0):

@saterHater is almost right. In his solution you have to set the internal field separator (IFS) when you're working if your filenames contain spaces. Instead of his solution, I personally would put the filenames into a `for loop`. Note that the `for loop` will have some memory overhead, but reading about CrunchMe I think that doesn't matter really.

```
#! /bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for ID in $(cat myfile.txt); do
    CrunchMe $ID
done
```

Otherwise, the link @chepner could be a solution. The following code uses less memory and more CPU resources, because you read the file line-by-line.

```
#! /bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r ID; do
    CrunchMe $ID
done < myfile.txt
```

Both scripts have the same output. In my test case that's:

```
1.txt
a 1.txt
lala .txt
```

I think you want to take a look at child processes when you're changing a lot of files. In that case you should consider the disk overhead, but that's off topic for this thread ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I'm a newbie answer-er, so my apologies if this isn't helpful.

The two things you need to know are the subshells `$()` and the variable prefix `$`:

```
cat $(cat myfile.txt) | while read ID ; do 
   mv $ID CruncMe
done
```

I am assuming you'll run this in the local directory where both your `myfile.txt` and ALL the other files are in.

Otherwise you can run a `find` subshell to locate the correct absolute path name of the `$ID` file.

Comment: also, its wise to used `$ID` inside double quote to prevent issues that could happen due to spaces in the `$ID`

Comment: I misread your question. I assumed you wanted all of the files in your filelist where to be moved.

Comment: If `myfile.txt` is huge this will eat too much memory, why don't you use a `while` loop and redirect it's stdin to `myfile.txt`? like `while read -r ID; do ... done < myfile.txt`

Comment: If you have spaces then you'll probably want a `while read` loop instead: `cat myfile.txt | while read file ; do echo $file; done`

Comment: Does this consider the possibility of filenames with spaces like "some file"?

Comment: This does not iterate over lines of the file: it iterates over *words* of the file (or possibly words *generated* via pathname expansion). See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).